# Discrete random variable-expected value

Tags: random-variables, conditional-expectation, expected-value

For each discrete random variable $X$ and a measurable set $B$, for which $P [B]> 0$,
show that
$E [X | B] = \frac{E [1_{B}X]} 
{P [B]}$. I have $E [X | B] = \frac{\sum x_{i} * P(\{X=x_{i}\}  \cap B) } 
{P [B]}$ and I don't know what next.

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{E[X 1_B]}{p[B]}=\frac{\sum_{\omega \in \Omega} x \times 1_B\times P(\{X=x\} ) } 
{P [B]}=\frac{\sum_{\omega \in B\cup B^{c}} x \times 1_B\times P(\{X=x\} ) } 
{P [B]}=\frac{\sum_{\omega \in B} x \times 1_B\times P(\{X=x\} )+0 } 
{P [B]}=\frac{\sum_{\omega \in B} x \times  P(\{X=x\} ) } 
{P [B]}=\frac{\sum_{\omega \in B} x \times  P(\{X=x\} \cap \{ \omega \in B\} ) } 
{P [B]}=\frac{\sum_{\omega \in \Omega} x \times  P(\{X=x\} \cap \{ \omega \in B\} ) } 
{P [B]}=\sum_{\omega \in \Omega} x \times  \frac{P(\{X=x\} \cap \{ \omega \in B\}}{P [B]} )=\sum_{\omega \in \Omega} x \times  P(\{X=x\}|B )=E(X|B)$

**another way**

$\frac{E[X 1_B]}{p[B]}=\frac{EE[X 1_B|X]}{p[B]}$

$=\frac{E(XE[1_B|X])}{p[B]}=\frac{E(Xg(X))}{p[B]}$

$=\frac{\sum_x x g(x) p(X=x)}{p[B]}=\frac{\sum_x x E(1_B|X=x) p(X=x)}{p[B]}$

$=\frac{\sum_x x p(B|X=x) p(X=x)}{p[B]}$

$=\frac{\sum_x x p(X=x|B) p(B)}{p[B]}$

$=\frac{p(B) \sum_x x p(X=x|B) }{p[B]}$

$=\sum_x x p(X=x|B)=E(X|B)$

note that $E[1_B|X]$ is a random variable that it is a function of $X$.

Comment: What did you prove?

Comment: I edited it. is it what you want or not?

Comment: Why do you use $\omega$?

Comment: since $E(X 1_B)=E(X 1_B(\omega))$ , $B$ is a  measurable set 
 so $B \in F$ in the probability space $(\Omega, F ,P)$ (so $B\subset \Omega$ such that $B\in F$

Comment: okey but i must write probably $\omega$ im my equation when i have X

Comment: i don't understand what you mean? clarify me. but for example $P(\{X=x\} \cap B)=P(\{\omega \in \Omega |X(\omega) =x\} \cap \{  \omega \in B\})$

Comment: okey :D I have the last question: Why i may wrote the first equation in your solution?

Comment: definition of expectation